# Unclosed session detected in logs in CQ5

Tags: aem, jcr

I am getting an unclosed session detected warning in the error.log . I have opened and closed all the sessions in the finally block. Still I am getting the warning. It has made the author instance very slow due to large number of unclosed session . Here are the error logs

```
04.06.2015 02:45:54.921 *WARN* [Finalizer] org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl Unclosed session detected. The session was opened here:  java.lang.Exception: Stack Trace
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:222)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.XASessionImpl.<init>(XASessionImpl.java:117)
        at com.day.crx.core.CRXSessionImpl.<init>(CRXSessionImpl.java:69)
        at com.day.crx.core.CRXRepositoryImpl.createSessionInstance(CRXRepositoryImpl.java:935)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createSession(RepositoryImpl.java:959)
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionFactory.createAdminSession(SessionFactory.java:42)
        at com.day.crx.sling.server.impl.SlingRepositoryWrapper.loginAdministrative(SlingRepositoryWrapper.java:76)
        at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProviderFactory.getResourceProviderInternal(JcrResourceProviderFactory.java:136)
        at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProviderFactory.getAdministrativeResourceProvider(JcrResourceProviderFactory.java:115)
        at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.tree.ResourceProviderFactoryHandler.login(ResourceProviderFactoryHandler.java:162)
        at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.tree.RootResourceProviderEntry.loginToRequiredFactories(RootResourceProviderEntry.java:95)
        at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverFactoryImpl.getResourceResolverInternal(ResourceResolverFactoryImpl.java:95)
        at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverFactoryImpl.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(ResourceResolverFactoryImpl.java:69)
        at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.helper.ResourceResolverContext.getResourceTypeResourceResolver(ResourceResolverContext.java:192)
        at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.helper.ResourceResolverContext.getParentResourceType(ResourceResolverContext.java:216)
        at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.getParentResourceType(ResourceResolverImpl.java:1136)
        at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.getParentResourceType(ResourceResolverImpl.java:1126)
        at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.isResourceType(ResourceResolverImpl.java:1151)
        at org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceUtil.isA(ResourceUtil.java:466)
        at com.adobe.cq.social.storage.index.AbstractBaseIndexHandler.checkResourceType(AbstractBaseIndexHandler.java:111)
```

This is the code snippet after which we get this warning.

```
private List<String>  rollOutPages(Collection<Page> pages) throws Exception
{
  final ResourceResolver adminResourceResolver=resourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
        List<String> rolledOutPages = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            //adminResourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
            for (Page page : pages) {
                final Collection<LiveRelationship> liveRelationships = relationShipManager.getLiveRelationships(page, null, null, false);
                for (LiveRelationship relationship : liveRelationships) {
                    rolloutManager.rollout(adminResourceResolver, relationship, false);
                    rolledOutPages.add(relationship.getTargetPath());
                }

            }
            adminResourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class).save();
            adminResourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class).logout();
            adminResourceResolver.close();
            return rolledOutPages;
        }
        catch (WCMException e) {
            adminResourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class).save();
            adminResourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class).logout();
            adminResourceResolver.close();
            LOG.error("Unable to create administrative resource resolver", e);
            throw new AbortException("Exception during rollout of pages",e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            adminResourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class).save();
            adminResourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class).logout();
            adminResourceResolver.close();
            LOG.error("Exception during rollout of pages", e);
            throw new AbortException("Exception during rollout of pages",e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            if(adminResourceResolver.isLive()||adminResourceResolver != null){
                adminResourceResolver.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

I have closed the session in the finally block. Still getting this warning. Can anybody please help me in understanding what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that you are closing the ResourceResolver, but not the Session you create when you call `adaptTo(Session.class)` on that ResourceResolver.  In the code below, I have changed that so that logout is called on the session in addition to the admin ResourceResolver being closed, and I also consolidated some duplication:

```
private List<String>  rollOutPages(Collection<Page> pages) throws Exception
{
        ResourceResolver adminResourceResolver;
        List<String> rolledOutPages = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            adminResourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
            for (Page page : pages) {
                final Collection<LiveRelationship> liveRelationships = relationShipManager.getLiveRelationships(page, null, null, false);
                for (LiveRelationship relationship : liveRelationships) {
                    rolloutManager.rollout(adminResourceResolver, relationship, false);
                    rolledOutPages.add(relationship.getTargetPath());
                }

            }
            Session session;
            try{
                session = adminResourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
                session.save();
            }
            finally{
                session.logout();
            }
            return rolledOutPages;
        }
        catch (WCMException e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to create administrative resource resolver", e);
            throw new AbortException("Exception during rollout of pages",e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LOG.error("Exception during rollout of pages", e);
            throw new AbortException("Exception during rollout of pages",e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            if(adminResourceResolver != null && adminResourceResolver.isLive()){
                adminResourceResolver.close();
            }
        }

    }
```

And code/troubleshooting will be much easier if you keep you follow the DRY principle--don't repeat yourself.  I see lots of duplicate code in your example.